# Deploying tensorflow model to endpoint in Vertex AI

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, endpoint, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I just got started using vertex ai with google cloud console. I am trying to deploy this mode to an endpoint. https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientnet/lite0/feature-vector/2

I successfully imported it into a google storage bucket and uploaded it to the model registry. However, when I attempt to deploy the model to an endpoint, I receive the following error.

`Due to an error, Vertex AI was unable to create endpoint "Feature Vectors". Additional Details: Operation State: Failed with errors Resource Name:  **path to project** Error Messages: Model server terminated: model server container terminated:  exit_code:       255 reason: "Error" started_at { seconds: 1669817118 } finished_at { seconds: 1669817421 } . Model server logs can be found at  **some link**`

I have tried export to Tensorflow version 2.8 and 2.1.

I tried importing the bucket that holds the model folder to the model registry and I also attempted to nest the model folder into a new folder and importing the new folder to the model registry. Both resulted in an upload error as they did not directly contained the saved_pb file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Dhruva, could you provide the stacktrace of this error? check the model server logs

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by importing the model from tensorflow and saving it locally using the save function (as opposed to downloading it off the tensorflow hub site)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

def get_model():
    model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientnet/lite0/feature-vector/2"

    IMAGE_SHAPE = (370, 240)

    layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_url, input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE+(3,))
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([layer])
    return model

model = get_model()

# this is the important line
model.save("featureVectorModel")
```